# Which css style do I need to set for opacity when printing from Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8, opacity

I have made a web page that consists of two overlapping images. I have applied an opacity filter to the top image so that both images are readable. The opacity is correct on the screen for most browsers including IE and Firefox. However, when I print the page to a real printer or to a PDF printer from IE version 7 or 8, only the top image is printed. The top image is correctly translucent when printing from IE 9 and Firefox.

Below is the code of my web page.

```
<html>
<body>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 366px; HEIGHT: 439px; TOP: 100px; LEFT: 100px; Z-INDEX: 1;">
    <IMG style="POSITION: relative; WIDTH: 366px; HEIGHT: 439px;" src="below_picture.png">
</DIV>
<DIV style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 366px; HEIGHT: 439px; TOP: 100px; LEFT: 100px; Z-INDEX: 390;">
    <IMG style="POSITION: relative; WIDTH: 366px; HEIGHT: 439px; FILTER: alpha(opacity=75);" src="above_picture.png">
</DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

Which css style do I need to set for opacity when printing from Internet Explorer 8?

Answer (score 6):

Try this it will give a blur effect in all the major browser including

```
.CLASS_NAME {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* other intelligent browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have to say this is the inbuilt problem of IE as that versions do not support opacity directly,

refer [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Now as you can see opacity is not directly supported by IE7-8 you can use filters with conditional css

Code [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)

```
.opaque2 {  // for IE5-7

    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

or for IE8

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
```

the order of the content should be

```
.opaque {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);                  // second!
}
```

Except you can use [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) that has one htc file that will help you to add css3 rules to almost all not supporting browsers..

I hope this will help..

Comment: Does this apply to printing too?

Comment: If Print Background and Images is allowed in browser then I think there should not be any problem then also I think we need to test on each IE..(as each IE have different mind) :)

Answer (score 1):

IE8 uses the `-ms-filter`  property.

older IE need the `filter: alpha(opacity=XX)`

```
img.namedClass {
    position: relative;
    width: 366px;
    height: 439px;

    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

this, on cascade, should solve the problem for all current browsers

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the positioning..you use position absolute on the parent div while your child is position: relative..it will not work on IE..and then use the opacity on the div not on the image..cheers..